# Is it un-pythonic to define a function inside of a class method?

Tags: python

PyLint told me that one of my class methods didn't need to be a method, but could just be a function in a class since it didn't use any class attribute. That made me do things I thought were "bad," but maybe they are  Pythonic. Is the following code what Python wants us to do?

```
class TestClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        def callbackfunction(text):
            print("hello")
        ParentClass.map_event_to_callback(ParentClass.event, callbackfunction)
```

where ParentClass.event emits `text` to its callback, but we'll just ignore that print `"hello"` instead. Even simpler:

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, text):
        def printhello(text):
            print("hello")
        printhello(text)
```

assuming I don't care about `text` or `printhello` after `__init__`.

Comment: Nope,that's fine. You could use a `lambda` too.

Comment: A function within a method is really no different from a function within an function.  Sometimes it makes sense, and when it does, there's no reason not to use it.

Comment: Thank you, @MartijnPieters and @TomKarzes! Putting a callback function inside of a class' `__init__` made me feel dirty, but I didn't know if there was a technical reason to avoid it or not. @MartijnPieters, if you make your comment an answer I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a nested function for a callback is just fine. It even gives that function access to any locals in the parent function (as closures).

You can use a `lambda` if all you need to execute is one expression:

```
class TestClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        ParentClass.map_event_to_callback(ParentClass.event, lambda text: print("hello"))
```